# How can I dynamically display an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How do i dynamically display an array that has multiple arrays.
The nested arrays have multiple objects.

e.g.

```
Var obj = 
[
  [
    {
      name: "Test 1",
      category: "Test 1"
    }, 

    {
      name: "Test 2",
      category: "Test 1"
    }, 
  ],

  [
    {
      name: "Test 1",
      category: "Test 2"
    }, 

    {
      name: "Test 2",
      category: "Test 2"
    }, 
  ]
]
```

So how do i dynamically display this and render it in a react component
I tried [below] and it works perfect and displays the first array-object, but i cant figure out a way to make it display the rest

```
list = obj[0].map((e, index) => {  
   return (
      <div key={index}>
         <p>{e.name}</p>
         <h6>{e.category}</h6>
      </div>
   )
})
```

```
return (
   <div>
      {list}             
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

One is to explicitly loop over the outer array and then the inner arrays:

```
const list = obj.map(cat => cat.map((e, index) => {  
   return (
      <div key={index}>
         <p>{e.name}</p>
         <h6>{e.category}</h6>
      </div>
   )
}));
```

The problem here is that `index` will not be unique on the page. As a general rule, you should not be using an array index as a component key anyway. You'd be better off using something like

```
   (
      <div key={`${e.name}-${e.category}`}>
         <p>{e.name}</p>
         <h6>{e.category}</h6>
      </div>
   )
```

Another approach would be to flatten the array:

```
const list = [].concat(...obj).map(e => (
  <div key={`${e.name}-${e.category}`}>
    <p>{e.name}</p>
    <h6>{e.category}</h6>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I think the correct way would be a recursive function.

Comment: @Vencovsky there's no "correct way" here. It's a matter of preference and there's nothing wrong with simple loops or flattening.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, sorry. I think that a recursive function would be a better way if the object can have more than 2 levels of nested arrays.

Comment: @Vencovsky sounds like the beginning of a good answer :) That said, since the OP is struggling with nested arrays, I'd guess they might struggle with recursion (no disrespect intended to OP... we all have to start somewhere!)

Comment: @Vencovsky in that case, it would be a good point since it would invalidate flattening and simple loops anyway ;)

Comment: @Dancrumb, is there a way how i can group the arrays when its dynamically being displayed, for example, if the first nested array has category "Test 1', i would like to append that to a div with that id, so now that "Test 1" div with have two children's nested in it, same goes for "Test 2", also how do i do dynamically create the div that i want to append to e.g. create only one of "Test 1" div then append the child, the divs will have to dynamically display as well because i have different arrays of arrays with different category name, Thanks!

Comment: @Abdulr, that's a very different question. I recommend you open a new question that  shows what you've attempted and what you're struggling with.